# How can I get the top 10 highest numbers from an array of number?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

If I have an array of objects all have a number in, how can I get a new array with the 3 highest numbers?

```
const exampleArray = [{
    "name": "Tim",
    "score": 76
},
{
    "name": "Lucy",
    "score": 23
},
{
    "name": "Jeremy",
    "score": 44
},
{
    "name": "Burns",
    "score": 66
},
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "score": 86
}
]
```

Expected return - where I have the highest scores.

```
let returnedArray = [{
    "name": "Tim",
    "score": 76
},
{
    "name": "Burns",
    "score": 66
},
{
    "name": "Mike",
    "score": 86
}
]
```

Comment: Sort the array by score, then take the first 3 elements of the sorted array.

Comment: The title says top 10, the question says top 3. Which is it?

Comment: do you want to maintain the order?

Answer (score 2):

You could get all scores, sort descending get top wanted values and filter the array.

```js
const
    array = [{ name: "Tim", score: 76 }, { name: "Lucy", score: 23 }, { name: "Jeremy", score: 44 }, { name: "Burns", score: 66 }, { name: "Mike", score: 86 }],
    values = array
        .map(({ score }) => score)
        .sort((a, b) => b - a)
        .slice(0, 3),
    top3 = array.filter(({ score }) => values.includes(score));

console.log(top3);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```